# Undo a change that was performed using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if there's a technique to simply undo a change that was done using Pandas.

For example, I did a string replacement on a few thousand rows of Pandas Dataframe, where, every occurrence of "&" in its string be replaced with "and". However after performing the replacement, I found out that I've made a mistake in the changes and would want to revert back to the Dataframe's most latest form before that string replacement was done.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: short answer: no. You would need to construct your DF again as it was before the change. PS if you are sure that there was no single substring "and" in the text before the change, then you can replace it back...

Comment: Main methods have an inplace parameter. If you set inplace=True, you save the df with your modifications. If you set inplace=False, you do not save the df and you can print your modifications. It helps for debugging :)

Comment: Lol.. CTRL + Z is the only thing that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cells structured in step, and the mess is because of running a couple of cells that have affected the dataset, you can stop the kernel and run all the cells from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to do this. If you're using the newest iteration of python and pandas you could do it this way:

`df.replace(to_replace='and', value='&', inplace=true)`

This is the way I learned it!

Comment: That wouldn't work, since it would replace all instances of the word "and", regardless of whether they were originally an "&".